# IceFaces accumulate view problem

Tags: multithreading, jsf, icefaces

I am uploading a file in IceFaces application through thread.
After file upload is done, I am showing javascript message.

Message is shown after some action or event is fired from view page.

I want to show them soon after uploading gets completed, in console it prints the successful message properly.

Following warning message is shown in console:

**[MainSessionBoundServlet] [1] views have accumulated updates**

Comment: @chetan Then you can post answer, so it might help someone having similar problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you forgot to add below line of code in faces-config file

```
<managed-bean>
     <description>Manages render calls to the Faces Context.</description>
     <managed-bean-name>renderManager</managed-bean-name>
     <managed-bean-class>com.icesoft.faces.async.render.RenderManager</managed-bean-class>
     <managed-bean-scope>application</managed-bean-scope>
 </managed-bean>

<managed-property>
    <property-name>renderManager</property-name>
    <value>#{renderManager}</value>
      </managed-property>
```